# Android Camera PreviewCallBack display image in dialog

Tags: android

I have a class that extends Camera.PreviewCallBack

In the onPreviewFrame, I call an AsyncTask, that checks for a QR Code

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    System.out.println("onPreviewFrame, should now decode");
    Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    new DecodeAsyncTask(previewSize.width, previewSize.height).execute(bytes);
}
```

If the decode is succesfull, It calls;

```
cameraManager.c.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,jpegCallback);
```

The method for takePicture is below;

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(cxt);

    settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    settingsDialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.qrimageviewer, null);
                   settingsDialog.show();
    Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));

    imageview = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qrimageview);

    imageview.setImageDrawable(image);

    try {
        System.out.println("TAKING PICTURE");


        Bitmap t1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(t1);//.createBitmap(t1,0, 0, 400, 100);

        File myExternalFile = new File(cxt.getExternalFilesDir("/MyFileStorage/"), System.currentTimeMillis()+".    jpg");
        myExternalFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 
}
```

When takePicture is called, I am trying to display the picture taken, in a dialog so the user can choose to save the image or not.

I am having trouble accessing the imageview to change its resource to a bitmap, created from a byte array.

the inflated layout, qrimageviewer.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qrimageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" 
        android:onClick="dismissListener"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is one of my several attempts to create and show the dialog;

```
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(cxt);
settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
settingsDialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.qrimageviewer, null);
settingsDialog.show();
Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
imageview = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qrimageview);
imageview.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Sorry if  have made any mistakes, or not provided enough info.
Thank You

--------UPDATE-------
It see that my problem now, is when I find the view.
I am getting this error;

```
04-03 14:23:33.800: E/AndroidRuntime(26060): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

I think it is because I am trying to find the view from an AsyncTask and it is failing and returning null, because the layout is inflated by the dialog.
Should i be trying to get the inflated view from the dialog?
Am i taking the wrong approach completely?
Or is it just not possible?

Thank You

Comment: Ok! So, if your issue is not with the picture callback and setting the image do the ImageView, please edit your question title, and share your asynk task or make another question here in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my own fault for reading to much and trying too many examples.

I was infalating a custom layout to use for the dialog.
Instead, I needed to programmatically create an ImageView, then add it to the dialog. 
Much simpler when you stop stressing and look at it in a different light.
Adding code for future reference.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(cxt);
                   settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(cxt);

Bitmap bitmapa = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapa);

settingsDialog.addContentView(imageView,  new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ));
settingsDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bitmap with the byte array and set it do your ImageView this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```